# how to setup user access media library?

Tags: media-library

I think this could be a simple answer but I can't really find.

except administrator, users are not able to see "media library".

Is there anyway to setup to show (display on dashboard) media library for non-admin users?
I may need give access by user-type or something else.

then they see what they uploaded.

```
 function my_files_only( $wp_query ) {
if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/upload.php' ) !== false ) {
    //if ( !current_user_can( 'level_5' ) ) {
        global $current_user;
        $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
    //}
}
 }
   add_filter('parse_query', 'my_files_only' );
```

Comment: I switch to `author` user and see Media Library just fine?..

Comment: no my user can not see the menu. do i need to set it up something?

Comment: What you describe is non-standard. (I think that is the point that @Rarst was making.) You don't need to set up anything but something _has already_ altered default behavior-- a plugin or a theme, probably. You need to find out what.

Comment: thanks now I understand, what I need to set it up. I modified  roles and capability and works great.